# Prevent button click event, add row to Listview on condition

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm new to xaml and c#, How can I prevent my button click event from adding a new row to Listview if the ProductID already exists

```
private void btnAddToOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //addtoorders
    if (listStocks.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)listStocks.SelectedItems[0];

        List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
        orders.Add(new Orders()
        {
            ProductID = row["productID"].ToString(),
            ProductName = row["productName"].ToString(),
            Price = Convert.ToDouble(row["sellingPrice"]),
            Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row["quantity"])

        });
        listOrders.Items.Add(orders);
      }
 }
```

Comment: Hope you are not new to ask questions. All necessary details should be given for others to understand what you are talking about.

Comment: Im very sorry Lex Li, Its my first time to post a problem here. (y)

Answer (score 1):

First of all why create a new object of Orders?

You can use LINQ which requires

```
  using System.Linq;
```

and then using

```
 var found = ordersobject.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Contains(row["productID"].ToString())); //Replace ordersobject with the Orders object that you have created
```

Finally if var found returns null then add the product i.e.,

```
private void btnAddToOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    //addtoorders
    if (listStocks.SelectedIndex >= 0)
    {

    DataRowView row = (DataRowView)listStocks.SelectedItems[0];

    var found = ordersobject.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Contains(row["productID"].ToString()));


        if(found == null)
        {
            //According to my knowledge a new object i.e., 
            //List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>(); doesn't have to be defined below 
            //provided that you have defined an object of class Orders before, 
            //unless you want to create various objects of Orders. 
            //Which will cause a lot of trouble in future.
            List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
            orders.Add(new Orders()
            {
                 ProductID = row["productID"].ToString(),
                 ProductName = row["productName"].ToString(),
                 Price = Convert.ToDouble(row["sellingPrice"]),
                 Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row["quantity"])

            });
            listOrders.Items.Add(orders);
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: it didn't solve my problem since I don't know anything about other stuffs like LinQ. But thanks for your effort. I Appreciated it very much. I'll work on my codes again and try to solve it. I'll post an update later.

Comment: Sad to know to that :( It's alright, we all learn step by step. If you are interested, you can check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/linq/ for beginner tutorials on LinQ. Pleasure is all mine, keep us updated and all the very best.

Answer (score 1):

I think this Code can help you:

```
 private void btnAddToOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
   //addtoorders
  if (listStocks.SelectedIndex >= 0)
  {
      DataRowView row = (DataRowView)listStocks.SelectedItems[0];
      Orders o=(Orders)row;
      List<Orders> orderlist=( List<Orders>)listOrders.ItemsSource;
      if(orderlist.Find(x=>x.PRoductID==c1.PRoductID)!=null)
        {
           MessageBox.Show("This Product already exists!");
        }
      else
       {
          listOrders.Items.Add(orders);
       }   

  }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

```
private void btnAddToOrder_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        //addtoorders
        if (listStocks.SelectedIndex >= 0)
        {
            DataRowView row = (DataRowView)listStocks.SelectedItems[0];

            Orders newOrder = new Orders()
            {
                ProductID = row["productID"].ToString(),
                ProductName = row["productName"].ToString(),
                Price = Convert.ToDouble(row["sellingPrice"]),
                Quantity = Convert.ToInt32(row["quantity"])

            };
            List<Orders> orders = new List<Orders>();
            //
            bool found = false;
            foreach(Orders order in orders)
            {
                if (order.Equals(newOrder))
                {
                    //if Found Order Equal NewOrder
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(found == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We are Found Order = NewOrder");
                return; //Exit From Method
            }
            //If Found == false
            orders.Add(newOrder);
            listOrders.Items.Add(orders);
        }
    }
```